# Latin HTML Theme translating text into english

Tags: html, themes, translation, responsive

I have downloaded a responsive HTML theme which is originally in Latin, to customize and develop a website.

I put the title as"Decalog" (Name of the site)

```
<title>DecaLog</title>
```

But when I apply changes, My chrome browser automatically translates and changes this to "Decalogus". While I understand the translate process, I don't want this to happen. I believe this will also translate text I put in later in the website. How to prevent this ?

EDIT:

As previously mentioned, it ios messing up the text. I add english text and it automatically translates it, (Decalog keeps changing into Decalogus everywhere in the document)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the lang attribute with html as,

html lang="en"

It is used to declare the language of a Web page or a part of it, saying this webpage default language is english. 
This helps browsers & search engines to detect the language of you webpage.

OR if this doesn't work out, just disable the chrome auto translation from settings.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use this method in your HTML
: `<p translate="no"></p>` in whatever you don't want to be translated